# Handle Duplicate Configurations

Tags: sql, sql-server, plsql

I have a table with records like below

```
No. Parameter   STATUS
1   STO         INACTIVE
2   STO         ACTIVE
3   BOS         ACTIVE
4   KYC         INACTIVE
5   KYC         INACTIVE
6   ACC         ACTIVE
7   ACC         ACTIVE
```

Now result I am interested in is as follows:

```html
No. Parameter   STATUS
2   STO         ACTIVE
3   BOS         ACTIVE
4   KYC         INACTIVE
6   ACC         ACTIVE
```

That is, I want to select data on basis of **STATUS** .

1. Condition -- If STATUS is **ACTIVE** for both case of same Parameter - select first coming **ACTIVE**
2. Condition -- If STATUS is **INACTIVE** for both case of same Parameter - select first coming **INACTIVE**
3. Condition -- If STATUS is **ACTIVE** & **INACTIVE** for same Parameter - select **ACTIVE**

Please help for same query which I can use to write in my Procedure.

Comment: Yes , I used below query but it's displaying first coming record only. I want it to be as per condition. –   

select name,status,count(name)
from my_table
where process_exec_num = 1
group by name,status having count(name) in (1,2);

Comment: Add your query to the post, not as comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is a UNION ALL solution, first part selecting ACTIVE rows, second one selecting INACTIVE bit only if no active exists:

```
select No, Parameter, STATUS from table
where status = 'ACTIVE'
UNION ALL
select No, Parameter, STATUS from table t
where status = 'INACTIVE' and not exists (select * from table
                                          where parameter = t.parameter
                                            and status = 'ACTIVE')
order by no, parameter
```

Or, perhaps better - **now improved**

```
select MIN(No) as No, Parameter, STATUS
from table t
where status = 'ACTIVE' or not exists (select * from table
                                       where parameter = t.parameter
                                         and status = 'ACTIVE')
group by Parameter, STATUS
order by no, parameter
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.
I am able to retrieve condition - 3 i.e. If STATUS is ACTIVE & INACTIVE for same Parameter - select ACTIVE

Also ,I want to select data on basis of these conditions. 

1.Condition -- If STATUS is ACTIVE for both case of same Parameter - select first coming ACTIVE

2.Condition -- If STATUS is INACTIVE for both case of same Parameter - select first coming INACTIVE

3.Condition -- If STATUS is ACTIVE & INACTIVE for same Parameter - select ACTIVE

Please guide.

Comment: @JatinGupta, what about my recent change, tried it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do what you want with conditional aggregation:

```
select parameter,
       max(case when min(status) = max(status) then max(status) else 'ACTIVE' end) as status,
       coalesce(min(case when status = 'ACTIVE' then id end), min(id)) as id
from table t
group by parameter;
```

An alternative approach for this sort of prioritization is to use `row_number()`:

```
select parameter, status, id
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by parameter
                                order by status asc, id
                               ) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  the `order by status asc` uses the fact that `ACTIVE` is alphabetically before `INACTIVE`.  This is just the simplest way to incorporate that logic.

EDIT (from Silvain):

SQL Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6712f9/4).

Comment: I was just about proposing the same answer. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6712f9/4 (I don't know if it is appropriate to edit an answer to add a link to the corresponding SQLFiddle...)

Comment: I used this code.. but it's throwing ORA Error - Missing Left Parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

I used below query in CURSOR

```html
CURSOR cCnfgTypData IS
  select distinct name, description, STATUS
  from stg_xml_cpdb_configuration
  WHERE process_exec_num = 1
  AND STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
  UNION ALL
  select name, description, STATUS
  from stg_xml_cpdb_configuration t
  where process_exec_num = 1
  and STATUS = 'INACTIVE'
  and not exists (select * from stg_xml_cpdb_configuration
  where name = t.name 
  and STATUS = 'ACTIVE') order by name, description;
```

I am able to retrieve data, but I also want two more column data (one is unique constraint) .
I used below code -

```html
CURSOR cCnfgTypData IS
  select distinct name, description, STATUS, xml_configparamdb_id, xml_configuration_id
  from stg_xml_cpdb_configuration
  WHERE process_exec_num = 1
  AND STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
  UNION ALL
  select name, description, STATUS, xml_configparamdb_id, xml_configuration_id
  from stg_xml_cpdb_configuration t
  where process_exec_num = 1
  and STATUS = 'INACTIVE'
  and not exists (select * from stg_xml_cpdb_configuration
  where name = t.name 
  and STATUS = 'ACTIVE') order by name, description;
```

But now I get all records without satisfying conditions.

1.Condition -- If STATUS is ACTIVE for both case of same Parameter - select first coming ACTIVE

2.Condition -- If STATUS is INACTIVE for both case of same Parameter - select first coming INACTIVE

3.Condition -- If STATUS is ACTIVE & INACTIVE for same Parameter - select ACTIVE

NOte - Here, xml_configuration_id contains UNIQUE DATA